# IspObjectToken::DisplayUI

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, sapi

I tried to use IspObjectToken::DisplayUI from SAPI 5.4 in C# and I don't know what are the exact parameters for that.

```
void ISpObjectToken.DisplayUI(ref _RemotableHandle HWndParent, string pszTitle, string pszTypeOfUI,IntPtr pvExtraData, uint cbExtraData,object punkObject)
```

I know that we should put null for `pszTitle`, and for `pszTypeOfUI` we should use one of supported UI like `MicTraining` or `AddRemoveWord` , But I know nothing about the rest of it. I'm using windows 7 on my laptop.

**Edit:** This is the code that I wrote and obviously it's not working.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int pfSupported;
        string extradata = "test\0";
        IntPtr pvExtraData = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(extradata);
        uint cbExtraData = (uint)extradata.Length * sizeof(Char);
        Speechlib._RemotableHandle rh = new Speechlib._RemotableHandle();
        rh = getRemotableHandle(this.Handle);
        ISpObjectToken isot = (ISpObjectToken)new SpObjectToken();

        isot.IsUISupported("AddRemoveWord", pvExtraData, cbExtraData, null, out pfSupported);
        if (pfSupported == 1)
        {
            isot.DisplayUI(ref rh, null, "AddRemoveWord", pvExtraData, cbExtraData, null);
        }
    }
    SpeechLib._RemotableHandle getRemotableHandle(IntPtr handle)
    {
        IntPtr address = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(IntPtr.Size);
        Marshal.WriteIntPtr(address, handle);
        return (SpeechLib._RemotableHandle)Marshal.PtrToStructure(address, typeof(SpeechLib._RemotableHandle));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always pass nulls and 0 (as appropriate) to get the default behavior for the type of UI.

If you want specific behavior, then what you pass depends on the type of UI, and on the underlying engine.

For the Microsoft Desktop SR engine, the pUnkObject parameter should always be NULL.  There are no (interesting) valid non-null values for this parameter.
pvExtraData and cbExtraData can be non-NULL if pszTypeOfUI is either [SPDUI_UserTraining](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee431894(v=vs.85).aspx) or [SPDUI_AddRemoveWord](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee431896(v=vs.85).aspx).

When pszTypeOfUI is [SPDUI_AddRemoveWord](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee431896(v=vs.85).aspx), then pvExtraData can be a standard null-terminated string containing the word to add to the lexicon.  cbExtraData should be the size of the string in bytes, including the terminating null.

When pszTypeOfUI is [SPDUI_UserTraining](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee431894(v=vs.85).aspx), then pvExtraData should be a [double-null-terminated string](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/10/08/9904646.aspx) containing a set of training sentences.  cbExtraData should be the size of the entire string in bytes, including both terminating nulls.

I go into a bit more detail on my [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tsfaware/archive/2013/09/12/displayui-and-the-extra-data-parameters.aspx).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comprehensive explanation. I would be really grateful if you just take a look at the code that I added to this question. Thanks again.

Comment: @lesley-gushurst has a fairly reasonable implementation.

Comment: If we use the below way, can we use it for "AddPronunciation"? Because it will bring up the pronunciation window but it doesn't add the word to it. Do you know any solution for that? Is using `IspObjectToken` instead of `ISpeechRecognizer` help to solve this problem? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your code is a bit over complicated. With the right references, inclusion of System.Speech and SpeechLib I got the following to work and launch the AddRemoveWord dialog.

```
using SpeechLib;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SpSharedRecoContext spSharedRecoCtx = new SpSharedRecoContext();
            ISpeechRecognizer ispSpeechReco = spSharedRecoCtx.Recognizer;
            if (ispSpeechReco.IsUISupported("AddRemoveWord", null))
            {
                ispSpeechReco.DisplayUI(this.Handle.ToInt32(), "Additional Training", "AddRemoveWord", "Example");
            }
        }
```

Eric also covers how to do custom grammar training using DisplayUI() [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854820/how-to-train-a-user-who-is-using-my-code-which-implements-system-speech-and-spee)